# axis is not shown in plot bar kind=bar in pandas

Tags: pandas, plot, analysis

I am not getting axis on the bar plot.
I copied the same code and getting the required graph but the issue is with axis.
The columns of my data frame is age and target .

```
df=heart_df.groupby(['age','target']).size()
df=df.unstack()
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I used the following source DataFrame (*heart_df*):

```
    age target  amount
0    50     T1       1
1    50     T1       1
2    50     T2       1
3    50     T2       1
4    50     T2       1
5    55     T1       1
6    55     T1       1
7    55     T1       1
8    55     T2       1
9    55     T2       1
10   55     T2       1
11   55     T2       1
12   60     T1       1
13   60     T1       1
14   60     T1       1
15   60     T2       1
16   60     T2       1
17   60     T2       1
18   60     T2       1
19   60     T2       1
```

To create the source DataFrame for bar plot, I ran:

```
df = heart_df.groupby(['age', 'target']).size()\
    .rename_axis(('Age', 'Target')).unstack()
```

Note that I changed index column names to names starting
with upper case letters (it looks better in the plot).

After *unstack*:

- *Target* becomes the name of column index.
- *Age* becomes the name of row index.

Print *df* and its *columns* and *index* to look for details.

And to print the plot, with *y* axis named, I ran:

```
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of cases');
```

(change the *y* axis title to whatever you wish).

The result is:

[image]

Is this what you want? Both axes have their titles.